# Assign default value 6 months in the past to datetime variable on data.stackexchange.com

Tags: sql, sql-server, data.stackexchange.com

I found  a query on data.stackexchange.com ([Interesting unanswered questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions)) and wanted to make a variation with an optional datetime variable to avoid getting questions that are very old in the results.

I hard coded a date six months in the past `DECLARE @FromDate datetime = ##FromDate?2018-06-01##` which works okay for now, But I would like to future-proof it.

Is it possible to assign a default date which is dynamically six months in the past in a not-too-round about way?

[Interesting unanswered questions with date limit](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/969880/find-interesting-unanswered-questions-with-date-limit?FromDate=2018-06-01&UserId=1725871)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go

```
DECLARE @Fromdate DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH,-6,GETDATE())
```

Comment: While this does solve the issue, the input field below the query dissapears, It's the `##` part of the declaration that does this. question is whether I can put your solution into that declaration

Comment: `DECLARE @Fromdate DATETIME = ##FromDate?DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE())##` works a charm

Comment: Yeah, what I've posted is meant to guide in the right direction.  So long as its helped then I'm a happy DBA.